# Calculated field - If date = date then return another date, otherwise date

Tags: calculated-column, date-time

I have two fields, StartDate and NewDate. The NewDate field, I want to calculate based on StartDate and return a date.

If the Start date is greater than or equal to 3/31/2016, then enter 4/26/2017 in NewDate field. If not, then leave the field blank.

```
=IF([StartDate]>="3/31/2016","4/26/2017","01/01/2010")
```

I have read that you can't leave the field blank, so I stuck 1/1/2010 in there to get around that issue, for now.

But, this formula still doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The NewDate field shows up blank (and I thought it couldn't). I made sure the date results are set for a Date. I edited my start date all sorts of ways to see what happens, and it's always blank.

Help?

Comment: Is your StartDate column set to dateonly or datetime?

Comment: ahh start date IS date and time. I should change that to just date, right?

Comment: Yes... Please check my answer

Comment: wait.. I was wrong.  Both StartDate and NewDate are set to date only

Comment: Your calculated column's return type must be datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below options first.

1. **StartDate** of type Datetime with **date only** option.
2. Choose The data type returned from your formula must be **DateTime**.

Than Below formula.

```
=IF([StartDate]>=Date(2016,03,31),Date(2017,04,26),Date(2010,01,01))
```

Comment: StartDate is Date only. Return data type is Date and Time formatted as Date Only. I changed the return format to Date & Time and it still didn't work.

Comment: return type for the calculated column must be date time.  Check here...http://nbsp.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/Photos/eusp/2010-11-12-QOTD-01_10658.png

Comment: Yes. That's what StartDate and NewDate are both set to. The formula returns 1/1/2010 now, no matter what the StartDate is.

Comment: Use updated formula from answer

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Is that works...?

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you so much. I apologize for being so late in responding, but I was called away and couldn't get back to this. I understand what you have done here, and it makes sense and it does work. Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you Please give justice to my answer if it helps you?

Comment: If you can mark the answer than others can get benefit from it.

Comment: Sorry Hardik. I am new to this board and didn't realize. I believe I have marked it , but if I need to do something else to acknowledge your help, let me know. I really do appreciate it! Thank  you.

Comment: Please upvote it as well so i get few reputation as a help

Comment: ok I think I figured it out

Comment: What did you figure out?

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare a date to a date, not a string. Try this:

`=IF([StartDate]>DATE(2016,06,01),"4/26/2017","")`

Dates can't be set blank through a workflow. It worked fine for me with a calculated field. This also worked fine for me for a "Date and Time" field... it doesn't have to be date only.